# NoMethodError when assigning returned values to variables from a Salesforce SOQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, salesforce

Im Having an issue with the [Databasedotcom](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom) ruby gem in trying to assign response values to global variables from a SFDC Soql query in a Ruby on Rails project.

I'm currently getting a `NoMethodError` on the `CaseNumber` part of the `$_CASENUMBER` variable.

### Code

```
case_list = @@client.query("SELECT CaseNumber, Product__c FROM Case")
_case = case_list.first

$_CASENUMBER = _case.CaseNumber
$_PRODUCT = _case.Product__c

response = "The Case Number > #{$_CASENUMBER} and the Product is > #{$_PRODUCT}"
response.to_s
```

Now this code works fine when in just a plain Ruby script, but when in a rails environment it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that `case` is a keyword in ruby, try renaming your variable to something else...

Comment: @UriAgassi Added _ to the front of case to ensure that wasn't the case, same result though :/

Comment: Could you print the whole error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue by switching to the [Restforce Gem](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) and researching the object relationships within the salesforce environment i was working with.  :)